# Replacing a line in .txt file corrupts the next line and the line itself

Tags: c++, file

I want to update a part(sub-info) of a line(info) in a text file. It does update/replace the part of the line but corrupts the beginning of the next line. Also a part of the old line still remains in the updated line.

---

*product.txt file:*

```
|    Product   |   |Stock |  |Wholesale|   |Retail|   |  Product   |   |  Note    |
|     Name     |   |amount|  |  price  |   |price |   |  Supplier  |   |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Big Banana,          210       ,270,        310     ,kashem suppply     ,no note   
Apple,               50        ,100,        145     ,Khulna Fruits      ,No note   
Dragon Fruit,        9         ,700,        890     ,Indo-Asian farms   ,Costly    
Orange,              88        ,70,         100     ,Khulna Fruits      ,rotten    
Guava,               16        ,120,        150     ,Sandwip Agro       ,Dababy    
Goat Fry,            2         ,1000,       1700    ,Sandwip Agro       ,Costly    
Dumb Miraz,          9         ,700,        890     ,Indo-Asian farms   ,Cannibal
```

---

How code meant to work:

- Open `product.txt` which contains all the information of products. Show information to user. then ask to update a sub-info of a product.
- Take product name. Then program will find out the line containing the product name. `strstr()` is used as product name is `sub-string` of the whole line `string`.
- Take sub-info that need to be updated. Use `.find()` to find the sub-info, `.replace()` to replace it with `new_sub_info`.
- Now Replace the line in text file with the updated line. `prev` is used to keep track of the line pointer and to seek to the beginning of that-line.

*confusion: How pointer behave/change/increase with `getline()`.*
Observation: First line seeks 90(`char`?)(`prev`=90). the next lines seeks 84(`prev`+=84) each. But all lines are equal in size (84 `char` long).

*Windows 10 OS*

Related code:

```
void get_Untill_Int(int* pInput)//keep taking input until input is `int or float`; safer than cin
{...}

string StringInput()  //returns null-terminated string
{...}

void Admin_Show_ProductFromFile() //shows product informations and give further option to user
{
    string Product_whole_info_line;

    fstream Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile; //fstream used. cause want to both read and write
    Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.open("product.txt"); //.txt file open.

    if (!Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile)
    {
        perror("Product File failed to open");
        return;
    }

    /*----------------show product info-------------------------*/
    while(getline(Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile, Product_whole_info_line))
    {
        cout<<" "<<Product_whole_info_line<<'\n';
    } 
    /*-----------product info shown-------------------------*/

    /*------------Edit a particular sub-info of a product----------------------*/

    Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.clear(); //failbit not in failed state
    Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.seekg(0);//go back to the start of .txt file

    string tempProductName; //whose sub-info will be edited/updated

        cout << "Enter product Name: ";  /*the product to be searched to edit its' sub-info*/
        tempProductName = StringInput();      

        char chartempProductName[tempProductName.length()+1];
        char charProduct_whole_info_line[Product_whole_info_line.length()+1];//will need for strstr() later.
        
        streampos prev=Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.tellg(); //save current pointer of .txt file(confused with names)
        while (getline(Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile, Product_whole_info_line))//take line containing product info
        {
            strcpy(chartempProductName, tempProductName.c_str());//convert string to char[]
            strcpy(charProduct_whole_info_line, Product_whole_info_line.c_str());//convert string to char[]

            if (strstr(charProduct_whole_info_line, chartempProductName))//wnated product_line found by comparing chartempProductName
            {
                string product_sub_info, newProduct_sub_info;
                cout << "Enter info that need to be changed: ";  /*which sub-info of product_line to be updated*/
                product_sub_info = StringInput();        /*product sub_info*/
                cout<<"enter updated info: ";
                newProduct_sub_info = StringInput();

                Product_whole_info_line.replace(Product_whole_info_line.find(product_sub_info),product_sub_info.length(),newProduct_sub_info);
                //product sub-info has been updated inside program. Now we have to replace/update the line in the .txt file
                
                Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.seekg(prev);//seek the pointer back to the beginning of the .txt file
                Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile << Product_whole_info_line<<'\n';
                break; //break `while loop`. cause product found and info updated.
            }
            prev = Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.tellg(); //current position of the getline input pointer
        }
    }

//print updated file
    Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.clear();
    Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.seekg(0);//go back to the start of .txt file
    while(getline(Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile, Product_whole_info_line))
    {
        cout<<" "<<Product_whole_info_line<<'\n';
    } 

    Read_n_Write_ProductFrom_txtFile.close();//.txt file closed.

}
```

I think the problem is in `.seekg()` or the pointer of text file(`streampos prev`). But I still can't figure out.

---

Input:

```
Enter product Name: Big Banana
Enter info that need to be changed: 210
enter updated info: 220
```

Output:

```
|    Product   |   |Stock |  |Wholesale|   |Retail|   |  Product   |   |  Note    |
|     Name     |   |amount|  |  price  |   |price |   |  Supplier  |   |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BigBig Banana,          220       ,270,        310     ,kashem suppply     ,no note   
le,               50        ,100,        145     ,Khulna Fruits      ,No note   
Dragon Fruit,        9         ,700,        890     ,Indo-Asian farms   ,Costly    
Orange,              80        ,70,         100     ,Khulna Fruits      ,no note   
Guava,               16        ,120,        150     ,Sandwip Agro       ,Dababy    
Goat Fry,            2         ,1000,       1700    ,Sandwip Agro       ,Costly    
Dumb Miraz,          9         ,700,        890     ,Indo-Asian farms   ,Cannibal
```

Expected output:

```
|    Product   |   |Stock |  |Wholesale|   |Retail|   |  Product   |   |  Note    |
|     Name     |   |amount|  |  price  |   |price |   |  Supplier  |   |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Big Banana,          220       ,270,        310     ,kashem suppply     ,no note   
Apple,               50        ,100,        145     ,Khulna Fruits      ,No note   
Dragon Fruit,        9         ,700,        890     ,Indo-Asian farms   ,Costly    
Orange,              88        ,70,         100     ,Khulna Fruits      ,rotten    
Guava,               16        ,120,        150     ,Sandwip Agro       ,Dababy    
Goat Fry,            2         ,1000,       1700    ,Sandwip Agro       ,Costly    
Dumb Miraz,          9         ,700,        890     ,Indo-Asian farms   ,Cannibal
```

Comment: It is hard to edit formatted text data in a file. Whatever you write has to be the same size as whatever you had in that cell, including padding, or you'll write over something or leave traces of the old data. Standard procedure when you have to edit a file is to read into memory, edit in memory, and then write a new file over top of the old one. You can do in place editing, but it's much, much harder.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? Line ending translation would throw your count off since the file will have CR/LF pairs at the end of each line. It's often easier, depending on the size of the file, to just read the whole file into memory, make whatever changes are necessary, then write the whole file back out.

Comment: @user4581301 but wouldn't completely rewriting the whole text file take much more space and time if the file is comparatively large?

Comment: Yup. And there are a lot of good reasons to not rewrite. Most of the time people asking questions here don't have a good reason, so I always pitch going the easy route first. Please do not take that as an insult if you are one of the few where in-place editing is the right choice.

Comment: If the lines are truly the same length, open the file in binary mode, not text mode, and use 85 for the length of each line. The `\r\n` of Windows text files won't be translated into `\n` in binary mode.  Then the seeks will be accurate.  Make sure you write exactly 85 bytes back out, including the `\r\n` at the end.