# Trying to prepend or modify existing line is overwriting part of the next line

Tags: python, windows, file, io

I have a main file and a temp file. In both files are records following the format (colons and |'s included)

`Name:<name>|Field1:<int>|Field2:<str>|Field3:<str>|LockPID:<process id>`

The tmp file only has one record, the main file may have one or more records on concurrent lines

lets say i want to modify the record in the mainfile that has the name Charles, i open the mainfile in "read" mode, and look for the contents of the byte number of the line with Charles name using the following function:

```
def find_line_byte_position(file_name, target_line):
    with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
        current_byte_position = 0

        for line in file:
            if line.startswith(target_line.encode()):
                return current_byte_position

            # Increment the byte position by the length of the current line, including newline character(s)
            current_byte_position += len(line)

    # If the target line is not found, return -1 or raise an exception, as desired
    return -1
```

assuming i find the byte position, i can now seek that line

```
    if recordExistsInMain:
        main_file = open(main_filename, "r+")
        main_file.seek(byteToSeek)
        main_file.write(line)
```

If I am adding information, I find that text from the following line disappears. What is going on?

Here is an example, before and after (note i renamed the fields for the purpose of this question)

```
records.txt
Name:TAZ|Foo:100|Bar:
Name:CHRIS|Foo:200|Bar:
```

```
records.txt
Name:TAZ|Foo:100|Bar:yep
e:CHRIS|Foo:200|Bar:
```

I can see that by adding 3 characters in line 1 i lost 3 characters in line 2. But I did not lose the newline, so I'm confused on how to fix this.

I tried using ljust to add padding to the first line in the main record, then modifying it, but text still got eaten from line 2. and spaces take up bytes that i'd rather not use on them anyway

[Replacing a line in .txt file corrupts the next line and the line itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68108364/replacing-a-line-in-txt-file-corrupts-the-next-line-and-the-line-itself)
^this looks like the same problem, but i dont understand exactly how to implement the solution. of which the only one really provided was padding with spaces (which i tried and failed to implement i guess) or to read and write the whole file (which i think is a little silly? maybe that is the solution)

note: i wanted to make it so multiple people could open the same script and modify the same file simultaneously, and my idea to make it work was just to add a lockPID to each record if it was being modified - only the correct python process with the same pid can modify that record. obviously this is unsecure but im just doing it for the sake of learning

Answer (score 1):

> If I am adding information, I find that text from the following line disappears. What is going on?

It's just the behaviour for a file: writing to the file stream at any location but the end will overwrite any data currently at that location.

Depending on your constraints, here are the main ways to handle the issue:

- the simplest and most common by far is to create a new file instead of updating in-place: copy the start of the file to a second file, write the new bit, copy the end of the file, then `rename()` the copy to the original
- if you have a lot more memory than the file size, you can just `read()` the end of the file (from the insertion point on) into memory, insert your data, then insert back the file content
- if you are memory-limited, then you have to do something similar but block by block from the end of the file: read the block starting at `end() - buflen` and write it back at `end() - buflen + offset`, then repeat going backwards until you have copied anything which follows the insertion point

The drawback of the first one is you need a second file and will have to copy a lot of data from one to the other, however nothing important gets touched until the `rename`, which is atomic. In the other two versions, if there's an error in the middle of the operation you end up with a broken file.

> note: i wanted to make it so multiple people could open the same script and modify the same file simultaneously, and my idea to make it work was just to add a lockPID to each record if it was being modified - only the correct python process with the same pid can modify that record.

This is very much temporally broken: two processes can open() the file, check the lockpid field, see that it's empty, and write to it, concurrently. They'll then both assume they have exclusive access to the record, and everything's broken.

For the reasons noted above (that you can't just write in the middle of a file) this also does not work at all because your records have variable size, so writing one record will affect the position of others, which means concurrent access to the file itself can't work.

For this scheme to be even remotely workable you need fixed-size blocks into which variable-size records can be written (this way separate blocks can safely be accessed independently), and then you need some sort of concurrent access control to blocks, of which there really is none without an orchestrating process (POSIX advisory locks are generally considered not great at best and broken at worst).

In all honesty, if sqlite only allows one writer at a time it's for good reasons and I would suggest you do the same.